# Problems rotating opengl camera

Tags: opengl, trigonometry, glut, vector-graphics

I cannot understand the math behind this problem, **I am trying to create an FPS camera where I can look freely with my mouse input.**

**I am trying to rotate and position my lookat point** with 180 degrees of freedom. I understand the easier solution is to glRotate the world to fit my perspective, but I do not want this approach. I am fairly unfamiliar with the trigonometry involved here and cannot figure out how to solve this problem the way I want to...

here is my attempt to do this so far...

*code to get mouse coordinates relative to the center of the window, then process it in my camera object*

```
#define DEG2RAD(a) (a * (M_PI / 180.0f))//convert to radians
static void glutPassiveMotionHandler(int x, int y) {
    glf centerX = WinWidth / 2; glf centerY = WinHeight / 2;//get windows origin point
    f speed = 0.2f;
    f oldX = mouseX;  f oldY = mouseY;

    mouseX = DEG2RAD(-((x - centerX)));//get distance from 0 and convert to radians
    mouseY = DEG2RAD(-((y - centerY)));//get distance from 0 and convert to radians

    f diffX = mouseX - oldX; f diffY = mouseY - oldY;//get difference from last frame to this frame

    if (mouseX != 0 || mouseY != 0) {
        mainCamera->Rotate(diffX, diffY);
    }
```

Code to rotate the camera

```
void Camera::Rotate(f angleX, f angleY) {
    Camera::refrence = Vector3D::NormalizeVector(Camera::refrence * cos(angleX)) + (Camera::upVector * sin(angleY));//rot up
    Camera::refrence = Vector3D::NormalizeVector((Camera::refrence * cos(angleY)) - (Camera::rightVector * sin(angleX)));//rot side to side
};
```

Camera::refrence is our lookat point, processing the lookat point is handled as follows

```
void Camera::LookAt(void) {
    gluLookAt(
        Camera::position.x, Camera::position.y, Camera::position.z,
        Camera::refrence.x, Camera::refrence.y, Camera::refrence.z,
        Camera::upVector.x, Camera::upVector.y, Camera::upVector.z
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera is defined by a position point (`position`) a target point (`refrence`) and a up-vector `upVector`. If you want to change the orientation of the camera, then you've to rotate the direction vector from the position (`position`)  to the target (`refrence`) rather then the target point by a [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Note, since the 2 angles are angles which should change an already rotated view, you've to use a rotation matrix, to rotate the vectors which point in an arbitrary direction.

Write a function which set 3x3 rotation matrix around an arbitrary axis:

```cpp
void RotateMat(float m[], float angle_radians, float x, float y, float z)
{
    float c = cos(angle_radians);
    float s = sin(angle_radians);

    m[0] = x*x*(1.0f-c)+c;   m[1] = x*y*(1.0f-c)-z*s; m[2] = x*z*(1.0f-c)+y*s;
    m[3] = y*x*(1.0f-c)+z*s; m[4] = y*y*(1.0f-c)+c;   m[5] = y*z*(1.0f-c)-x*s;
    m[6] = z*x*(1.0f-c)-y*s; m[7] = z*y*(1.0f-c)+x*s; m[8] = z*z*(1.0f-c)+c };
}
```

Write a function which rotates a 3 dimensional vector by the matrix:

```cpp
Vector3D Rotate(float m[], const Vector3D &v)
{
  Vector3D rv;
  rv.x = m[0] * v.x + m[3] * v.y + m[6] * v.z;
  rv.y = m[1] * v.x + m[4] * v.y + m[7] * v.z;
  rv.z = m[2] * v.x + m[5] * v.y + m[8] * v.z;
  return rv;
}
```

Calculate the vector form the position to the target:

```cpp
Vector3D los = Vector3D(refrence.x - position.x, refrence.y - position.y, refrence.z - position.z);
```

Rotate all the vectors around the z axis of the world by `angleX`:

```cpp
float rotX[9];
RotateMat(rotX, angleX, Vector3D(0, 0, 1));

los = Rotate(rotX, los);
upVector = Rotate(rotX, upVector);
```

Rotate all the vectors around the current y axis of the view by `angleY`:

```cpp
float rotY[9];
RotateMat(rotY, angleY, Vector3D(los.x, los.y, 0.0));

los = Rotate(rotY, los);
upVector = Rotate(rotY, upVector);
```

Calculate the new target point:

```cpp
refrence = Vector3D(position.x + los.x, position.y + los.y, position.z + los.z);
```

Comment: This is great.. No need for Glut :)

Answer (score 2):

`U_Cam_X_angle` is left right rotation.. `U_Cam_Y_angle` is up down rotation.

`view_radius` is the view distance (zoom) to `U_look_point_x`, `U_look_point_y` and `U_look_point_z`. 
This is ALWAYS a negative number! This is because you are always looking in positive direction. Deeper in the screen is more positive.
This is all in radians.

The last three.. `eyeX`, `eyeY` and `eyeZ` is where the camera is in 3D space.

This code is in VB.net. Find a converter online for VB to C++ or do it manually.

```
Public Sub set_eyes()

    Dim sin_x, sin_y, cos_x, cos_y As Single
    sin_x = Sin(U_Cam_X_angle + angle_offset)
    cos_x = Cos(U_Cam_X_angle + angle_offset)
    cos_y = Cos(U_Cam_Y_angle)
    sin_y = Sin(U_Cam_Y_angle)
    cam_y = Sin(U_Cam_Y_angle) * view_radius
    cam_x = (sin_x - (1 - cos_y) * sin_x) * view_radius
    cam_z = (cos_x - (1 - cos_y) * cos_x) * view_radius

    Glu.gluLookAt(cam_x + U_look_point_x, cam_y + U_look_point_y, cam_z + U_look_point_z, _
                        U_look_point_x, U_look_point_y, U_look_point_z, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F)

    eyeX = cam_x + U_look_point_x
    eyeY = cam_y + U_look_point_y
    eyeZ = cam_z + U_look_point_z

End Sub
```